# Logstash convert output date format

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

Im using logstash to get data from mysql and pass them to elasticsearch.
Unfortunately date format is default parsed to zulu time.
In need get data in datetime format
like `yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s` without t and z. Below is my logstash config

```
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/mysql/driver/mysql-connector-java-5.1.48/mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"
jdbc_user => root
jdbc_password => "secret"
tracking_column => "id"
use_column_value=> true
statement => "SELECT * FROM db.logs;"
schedule => " * * * * * *"
}

}

output {
elasticsearch {
document_id=> "%{id}"
document_type => "_doc"
index => "logs"
hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
sniffing => true
}

stdout{
codec => rubydebug
  }
}

filter {

date {
match => ["date", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
   }
}
```

In this case i received `"_dateparsefailure"`.
Im also tried use with mutate gsub and convert but not successed.

Now, the result is `"date" => "2020-02-28T09:18:18.000Z"`, but expected result is `2020-02-28 9:19:18`

Answer (score 1):

The date filter is useful but not always the best option.

First of all you can try to use this tool to find the right format for your date:
https://esddd.herokuapp.com/

If it doesn't work with date filter you have to add a template to elasticsaerch.

To do this you have to create a json file like  this one:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    "index_patterns": [                                                                                                                                                                                            
      "YOUR INDEX PATTERN"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    ],                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    "order": 0,                                     
    "mappings": {                                   
      "dynamic_templates": [                        
          {                                           
          "timestamp_fix": {                        
            "path_match": "THE NAME OF YOUR DATE FIELD",              
            "mapping": {                            
              "type": "date",                       
              "format": "FORMAT OF THE DATE YOU WANT"
            }                                       
          }                                         
        }                                           
      ]                                             
    }
```

and then you have to put in the logstash output this parameters:

```
 template => "PATH TO YOUR JSON FILE"
 template_name => "template_fix"
 template_overwrite => true
```

as described in logstash docs here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html

Let me know if it works! Good luck!